# Webpack: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: webpack, react-router

I have implemented React-router 1.0 in that I have implemented router like

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';

import App from './App';
import RepoPage from './pages/RepoPage';
import UserPage from './pages/UserPage';
import TaskList from './pages/TaskList';

var data=[{path:'/:UserPage/:Id',PageUrl:'./pages/UserPage'},
          {path:'/:RepoPage/:Id',PageUrl:'./pages/RepoPage'}
        ];
export default class Root extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  render() {
    const { history } = this.props;
    const ts=Object.keys(data).map(function(d){
        return(
             <Route path={data[d].path} component={require(data[d].PageUrl)} />
          );
       });
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route  path='/' component={TaskList}>
        </Route>
        <Route>
           {ts}
        </Route>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

as you can see in my code I am creating a variable ts and use that ts in render return function if I will use like it that it will give me warning like

**Webpack: the request of a dependency is an expression**

if I will commented that ts implemetation code then it will not give any warning.
can anyone please let me know what is the issue with it 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to react-router 2?